# Prove that $E (|xi -a|)$ is minimized when $a = md$

Tags: probability, statistics

This was given to us as an assignment, but I have no idea how I should do it.
Can someone give me some hints or give me a name or the topic?

$\min E(|X-a|) = E|X-md|$.

$X$ is an arbitrary continuous random variable.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\mathbb{E}|X-a|=\xi(a)=\int_a^{+\infty}(x-a)f_X(x)dx+\int_{-\infty}^a(a-x)f_X(x)dx$$

In order to minimize $\xi$ let's derivate it w.r.t. $a$

$$\xi'(a)=-\int_a^{+\infty}f_X(x)dx+\int_{-\infty}^af_X(x)dx=-[1-F_X(a)]+F_X(a)$$

Set it $=0$:

$$-[1-F_X(a)]+F_X(a)=0$$

$$F_X\left(a\right)=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$a=F_X^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

which is exaclty the definition of Median